# different types of line terminations(unix, windows, etc)

Tags: python, termination, linefeed

I'm note sure about conventions for different types of line termination in different programming languages. I know that there are 2 types, `1: line feed, 2: carriage-return, line feed.` My question is: how does readline in different programming languages, like python: `a = fd.readline();`, c/c++: `file.getline (buffer,100);`, java: `line = buf.readLine();` deal with line termination? If they are sensitive to these 2 different types of terminations, how do I treat them separately?

Comment: It's more a platform-dependent thing than a language-dependent thing.  And on Macs it's sometimes a 3rd type, just a `\r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly don't need to worry about it.  If you come to a point when something doesn't work, come back and ask about that.

Note however that what determines the line-ending convention is not which programming language you use, but the platform it runs on (*nix/Windows/Mac, all are different).

Comment: Actually, since Mac OS X, Mac became a unix, and therefore uses the simple `\n`. But it is true that it used to be `\r`